# Using OpenCV with Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use OpenCV in a Swift (iOS) project. The only complete project I've found is [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS), which has no documentation. There are a few example but all are using Objective-C. Like [this one](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation):

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
  CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
  CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

  cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels (color channels + alpha)

  CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to  data
                                                 cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                 rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                 8,                          // Bits per component
                                                 cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                 colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

  CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
  CGContextRelease(contextRef);

  return cvMat;
}
- (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
  CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
  CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

  cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channels

  CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to data
                                                 cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                 rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                 8,                          // Bits per component
                                                 cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                 colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

  CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
  CGContextRelease(contextRef);

  return cvMat;
 }
```

> After the processing we need to convert it back to UIImage. The code
>   below can handle both gray-scale and color image conversions
>   (determined by the number of channels in the if statement).

```
cv::Mat greyMat;
cv::cvtColor(inputMat, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

> After the processing we need to convert it back to UIImage.

```
(UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

  if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
  } else {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  }

  CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

  // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                     cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                     8,                                          //bits per component
                                     8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                     cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                     colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                     kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                     provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                     NULL,                                       //decode
                                     false,                                      //should interpolate
                                     kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                     );


  // Getting UIImage from CGImage
  UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  return finalImage;
 }
```

The final result:

[image]

I have no idea how to do such simple task in **Swift**, is it possible to convert these functions into **Swift**?

Comment: [komakai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834114/komakai) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367172/12695027) saying "As of version 4.4 OpenCV supports Swift out of the box. There are samples at: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/swift/ios"

Answer (score 3):

Swift doesn't work directly with C++. If you want to use C++ i your project, you have to write an Objective-C++ wrapper around your C++ code and call these wrapper methods from your Swift code.

[Here](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch) you can find an OpenCV project in Swift.